# List view column header index returns -1

Tags: c#, listview

I have a list view which i declared the column headers like below.

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader Debtorname;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader Message;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader Hpno;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader Status;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader Timestamp;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader sentBY;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader submitTime;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader debtorid;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader Account;

    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader Client;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader Batchno;
```

I populate the listviewitems like below.

```
 ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[lstSMSReport.Columns.Count]);
 lvi.SubItems[Debtorname.Index].Text = myReader["debtorName"].ToString();
 lvi.SubItems[Status.Index].Text = myReader["status"].ToString();

 lvi.SubItems[Timestamp.Index].Text = myReader["timestamp"].ToString();
```

When i run the above, i get the result i am expecting , however this two columnheaders below threw and exception.

```
  lvi.SubItems[Client.Index].Text = myReader["clientname"].ToString();
  lvi.SubItems[Batchno.Index].Text = myReader["batchno"].ToString();
```

When i put the two in try and catch. Then i realized a -1 is return as the index for the two columns. I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out why but still couldn't.

Please any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: what results are coming in myReader, clientname,batchno are availaible in myReader??

Comment: Yah are available. I even pass them to a string variable for a test .

Comment: Thank you but i found the error. It turns out my predecessor set a condition for the items which i am not i ware of . Thank you all.